# How to display an image from URL in Image component in Appery

Tags: image, url, ionic-framework, appery.io

I need to display an image using a URL that I receive from Push Notification. I tried many docs and blogs but couldn't find the correct solution. I don't want to download and store in DB.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way that i found to do this...
map the url to an image box and make it visible, set an events event to success, set action to Set property, set component name to what you want to show the image, set property to visibile and value to true leave check box empty as in this image [success to html function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dMZk.jpg)